# how to display center radius portion of map in android

Tags: android, gps, android-maps

I have searched a lot but didn't find it. so  sorry if this is a repeated question..

what i want is i want to highlight center portion of my map in android like this..

[image]

[image]

as you see above both image show circle of some radius..so any idea how yo achieve this ???

help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please Flow the path, Here is Demo work for display center radius portion of map in android

android-sdk -> add-ons -> addon_google_apis_google_inc_8 -> samples -> MapsDemo.

I think it help you.

Thanks.

Comment: thanks a lot..will just back to accept your answer if it helps :)

Comment: sorry but not worked on emulator and i don't have device right now for testing..-:(-:(